# How to eliminate items in the list of python

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python:

```
A=[[303  80]
   [390  43]
   [446  16]
   [471  16]
   [505  44]
   [557 225]
   [642  22]
   [672  15]
   [694  86]
   [702  76]]
```

Now I want to remove the rows `A[i]` which have a bigger summary value than the next item in the list.

```
A[i][0]+A[i][1] > A[i+1][0]
```

I code this lines:

```
B=[]
for i in range(len(A)-1):
  if A[i][0]+A[i][1]<=A[i+1][0]:
      B.append(A[i])
B.append(A[i+1])
```

I got this result:

```
B=[[303  80]
   [390  43]
   [446  16]
   [471  16]
   [505  44]
   [642  22]
   [672  15]
   [702  76]]
```

Are there any other ways which are shorter and quicker than this. Thank you very much.

Comment: What if you get back-to-back rows where the condition is met, do you exclude the first, second or both? I think you might want to apply this condition from last-to-first.

Comment: As @smci mentions, doing this naively like this might give you something you weren't expecting. If `f` is your function, then `f(A)` is not the same as `f(f(A))` for all possible inputs `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[a for a,b in zip(A, A[1:]) if sum(a)<=b[0]] + [A[-1]]
```

or

```
[a for i,a in enumerate(A[:-1]) if sum(a)<=A[i+1][0]] + [A[-1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through a `zip` of (current, next) items.

```
def filt(A):
    def cond(a, b):
        return a[0] + a[1] <= b[0]

    return [a for a, b in zip(A, A[1:]) if cond(a, b)] + [A[-1]]
```

You might even consider `itertools`, or better, `numpy` if performance is an issue.

**NOTE:** This solution falls for the problems I discussed in a comment above.

> As @smci mentions, doing this naively like this might give you something you weren't expecting. `filt(A)` is not the same as `filt(filt(A))` for all possible inputs `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` for an one-liner solution.

Without last element (because last element has no next element to compare):

```
expected_list = [A[i] for i in range(len(A)-1) if A[i][0] + A[i][1] <= A[i + 1][0]]
```

With Last element (**your expected output**):

```
expected_list = [A[i] for i in range(len(A)) if i==len(A)-1 or A[i][0] + A[i][1] <= A[i + 1][0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
B=[d  for c,d in enumerate(A) if c < len(A)-1 and A[c][0]+A[c][1] <= A[c+1][0]]
B.append(A[-1])
```

Comment: You can directly add the lists together. `B = [...] + [A[-1]]`. (Avoids the `append`.)